Automatically blending low motion frames to speed up a video
I have a long video clip of driving that I would like to speed up. The video is a mix of driving (where there's a lot of movement in the scene) and waiting at stoplights (where there is almost no movement). What tool or technique could I use to blend frames with low motion to speed up the video? ffmpeg mpdecimate comes close, but it drops frames instead of blending them.

How much of a speedup do you need? And what does 'blending' mean to you? Collapsing a longish section of video into a shortish one, no matter how you do it, will involve dropping some frames. Consider keeping a (say) five second 'handle' on the end of one action clip, and similar at the beginning of the next. Then delete everything in between and do a two-second dissolve between the clips. Or whatever durations look appealing to you.

Thanks for the reply. I ended up writing a Python wrapper around ffmpeg that identifies frames with a low amount of change between them that then blends (averages) those frames instead of dropping them like ffmpeg mpdecimate does. It ends up being kind of a cool effect.
